# Combobox - Validate not called

Tags: plugins, lua, sdk, adobe, lightroom

Can someone please give me a hint for the combobox use (`LrView`) in the `lightroom` `sdk` 6.0?
My `validate` function is not being called. I don't know why. Anybody a hint what I'm doing wrong? 
Here is the code:

```
...
        local validateComboboxValue = function (view, value)
            outputToLog("in validate...")
            if(value ~= "Ja" and value ~= "Nein") then
                outputToLog("wrong value")
                view.value = "Ja"
                return false, "Ja", "Ungültige Eingabe"
            else
                outputToLog("valid value")
                return true, value, ""
            end
        end
    ...
        f:combo_box {
            font = "<system>",
            title = "enableSharing",
            enabled = bind 'enableSharingEnabled',
            items = {
                "Ja",
                "Nein"
            },
            value = bind 'sharingEnabled',
            width = LrView.share "label_width",
            immediate = true,
            validate = validateComboboxValue,
        },
    ...
```

I'm using Lightroom on a `Windows 10` machine.